# How to save the submitter name/editor name/creation time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, metadata, audit-trail

I'm building a gridview and a form in ASP.NET Visual C#.

I'd like my DB to save, for each entry/edit, the name of the submitter and time. I'm using SQL Server DB. How can it be done?.

Comment: You can insert it into a database? Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Each of your users have separate login? Save user info, time and machine name. For each entry save inputs/ouputs (for example in xml) or best way use database trigger to save updated/instered and deleted records.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code could look like:

```
foreach(var e in edits)
{
    // Depends on data structure.
    save(e.Name, e.Time);
    // or something like
    e.Save();
}
```

Edits could be a class that encapsulates some values. Use properties or methods to get the fields.